# PhoneGap 3.0.0: Unable To Instantiate Camera Plugin Object

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, cordova, camera

I am unable to instantiate the camera plugin object after onDeviceReady(). The navigator object is fine but navigator.camera === undefined which blows up in subsequent camera method calls. The camera plugin installed with out incident but I'm sure its a configuration issue. Just ran out of additional rocks to peek under. Thanks in advance for the assistance. Here are my files:

1. JS

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../phonegap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/vendor/jquery/jquery.2.0.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function formResize() {

       $('.btnlink').css('width', parseInt($('.form01').css('width').replace('px', '')));
       $('.form_wrapper').css('margin-top', parseInt($('.globalhdr').css('height').replace('px', '')) + 25);
       }
       $('window').resize(function() {
           formResize();
       });
   }
   var pictureSource;   // picture source
       var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

       // Wait for device API libraries to load
       //
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

       // device APIs are available
       //
       function onDeviceReady() {
           try {
               alert('onDeviceReady!');
               alert('navigator = ' + navigator);
               alert('navigator.camera = ' + navigator.camera);
               alert('navigator.camera.DestinationType = ' + navigator.camera.DestinationType);
               //                pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
               destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;            // navigator.camera.DestinationType;
               alert('destinationType = ' + destinationType);
           }
           catch(e) {
               alert(e);
           }
       }
       // A button will call this function
       //
       function capturePhoto() {
           alert('capturePhoto enter');
           // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
           navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
           alert('capturePhoto exit');
       }

       $('#camera').on('click', function(e) {
           try {
               e.preventDefault();
               capturePhoto();
           }
           catch(e) {
               alert(e);
           }
       });

       // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
       //
       function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
           alert('onPhotoDataSuccess enter');
           // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
           // console.log(imageData);

           // Get image handle
           //
           var capturedImg = $('#capturedImg');

           // Unhide image elements
           //
           capturedImg.css('display', 'block');

           // Show the captured photo
           // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
           //
           capturedImg.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
           alert('onPhotoDataSuccess exit');
       }

       // Called if something bad happens.
       //
       function onFail(message) {
           alert('Failed because: ' + message);
       }
   ```
2. Config.xml

   ```
   <widget id="com.phonegap.hello-world" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
       <name>MyApp</name>
       <description>
           Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
       </description>
       <author email="email@email.com" href="">MyApp Team</author>
       <feature name="Camera">
           <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
       </feature>
       <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
       <!--<plugins>-->
           <!--<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.camera" />-->
       <!--</plugins>-->
       <!-- more -->
   </widget>
   ```
3. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
       <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.phonegap.hello_world" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
           <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
               <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="BlackDollShows" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                   <intent-filter>
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                   </intent-filter>
               </activity>
           </application>
           <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       </manifest>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../phonegap.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../cordova.js"></script>
```

Simple but it took much acrobatics. Hope it is helpful in your project.